# Angularjs-ui-router not showing contents of template in browser

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am new Angular and trying to get a working example setup for Angular UI router

I researched some questions on stackoverflow but dont see the issue specifically. My Issue is that even though in browser debugging and network analysis i am seeing thatm my template html is called, still not seeing any content in browser.No errors in console

[AngularJS ui-router - template not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143546/angularjs-ui-router-template-not-displaying)

Using Angular 1.4.7 and corrosponding

Please find app.js below

```
(function(){
    angular.module('TestPrj',['ui.router']);

    angular.module('TestPrj').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/ReportB');
        $stateProvider
        .state('a', {
            url: '',
            abstract:true,
            controller:'mainController',
            controllerAs:'main',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
        })
        .state('a.b', {
            url: '/ReportB',
            controller:'B',
            controllerAs:'B',
            templateUrl: "partials/B.html"
        }); 
    });

    angular.module('TestPrj').run(function($rootScope,$state){
          $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
        });

})();
```

Controller b.js :

```
(function(){

angular.module('TestPrj').controller('B',B);

    function B($state){
        this.pageName = "Report a B";
    }

    B.$inject = ["$state","$stateParams","$scope"];

})();

Controller main.js
(function(){

angular.module('TestPrj').controller('mainController',mainController);

function mainController($state,$translate){

    }

mainController.$inject = ["$state","$translate"];

})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app="TestPrj" lang="en">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-translate-loader-url.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ui-mask.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/claimTypeSelection.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

partials/home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```

partials/B.html

```
<div>
    <div ui-view=""></div>  
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Also sharing screenshot of my project setup
[Angular Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vgcs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear why you are using an abstract state. The abstract state can provide data and enter/exit processing to child states. But it isn't activated. It does need a template.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states

In your example the child state does done of these and the abstract state was apparently meant to be used.

It would seem you didn't intend to make it abstract.

Update: The abstract url can't be blank. This is an example of your code with the url set:

```
.state('a', {
    url: '/a',
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'mainController',
    controllerAs: 'main',
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/11o6qF?p=preview

To see the functionality use this link: http://run.plnkr.co/CUN147Z4YdCKRxRw/#/a/b

Comment: Hi the intent of Abstract State in my code base was to prepend A to url of child state. That part is actually happening when i have the state as abstract. When i hit localhost:8080/TestPrj it changes to localhost:8080/TestPrj/#/ReportB. With Abstract commented out, thir redirect is not working. Also still this URL is not working localhost:8080/TestPrj/#/ReportB , which in my mind should work. I am seeing in network logs after clening browser cache that response is coming back from call, just not showing in the template

Answer (score 1):

Based off the digging I did I think the issue is that you made the first state abstract. There is an issue posted on the github for ui-router you can read [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/325). Also, consider the two plunkr examples

[without abstract](http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview)

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
            url: "/route1",
            templateUrl: "route1.html"
        })
          .state('route1.list', {
              url: "/list",
              templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
              controller: function($scope){
                $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
              }
          })

        .state('route2', {
            url: "/route2",
            templateUrl: "route2.html"
        })
          .state('route2.list', {
              url: "/list",
              templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
              controller: function($scope){
                $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
              }
          })
    })
```

[with abstract](http://plnkr.co/edit/30U36Y?p=preview)

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
            url: "/route1",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "route1.html"
        })
          .state('route1.list', {
              url: "/list",
              templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
              controller: function($scope){
                $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
              }
          })

        .state('route2', {
            url: "/route2",
            templateUrl: "route2.html"
        })
          .state('route2.list', {
              url: "/list",
              templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
              controller: function($scope){
                $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
              }
          })
    })
```

The second plunkr is a copy of the first except that abstract: true was added to the state and now it doesn't work.

Also, make sure you either clear your browser cache frequently or disable caching while using ui-router. It's pretty bad about serving cached results.

Comment: Hi the intent of Abstract State in my code base was to prepend A to url of child state. That part is actually happening when i have the state as abstract. When i hit http://localhost:8080/TestPrj it changes to http://localhost:8080/TestPrj/#/ReportB. With Abstract commented out, thir redirect is not working. Also still this URL is not working http://localhost:8080/TestPrj/#/ReportB , which in my mind should work. I am seeing in network logs after clening browser cache that response is coming back from call, just not showing in the template